# Facebook Graph API doesn't return the latest picture for an event

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Pretty sure this is a caching (server side not client) issue but no idea how to resolve.

Some events when I try and get the image just return the normal "question mark" static image (i.e. no image).

But when I check on facebook actual i can see the picture.

This is on the server side as its my python scripts that are getting the image via a call to urllib2.urlopen.

For Example:

http://graph.facebook.com/103299156441265/?fields=picture&type=large

returns

```
{
   "picture": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yA/r/gPCjrIGykBe.gif"
}
```

(which is the static quesitonmark image)

but on the real event page:

http://www.facebook.com/event.php?eid=103299156441265

I can see the image?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think the picture does not appear because [the event's information is not accessible through the Graph API](http://graph.facebook.com/103299156441265). Looking at the event page, it seems to have been created for [a non-public group](http://www.facebook.com/group.php?gid=156571546901). I think it is likely that you need to be a member of the group in order to access information about its events through the Graph API.